# Does $\int\limits_\mathbb{R} f_n\ dm\to \int\limits_\mathbb{R} f\ dm$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of measurable functions on $\mathbb{R}$ converging a.e. to $f$. If $0\leq f_n\leq f$ a.e. Does it follow that $\displaystyle\int_\mathbb{R} f_n\ dm\to\displaystyle\int_\mathbb{R} f\ dm$?

I think this is false but I can't think of any counterexample. Also, if I put another condition that $f_n$ is a sequence of integrable functions, does this imply that $f$ would also be integrable? Hence, the conclusion will hold by the Dominated Convergence Theorem? Thanks for any response.

Comment: monotone convergence theorem?

Comment: I was thinking MCT too but $f_n$ is not necessarily increasing. But can we force $f_n$ to be eventually increasing in this case since $f_n$ is always less than $f$ but $f_n$ needs to converge to $f$ at the same time?

Comment: Hint: If you want to use MCT, consider $g_m=\inf_{n\ge m}f_n$

Comment: Another similar hint is using Fatou Lema!

Comment: Now I am convinced that it would still be true. Thank you @fedja!

Comment: Fatou's lemma also works beautifully. Thank you @Ale.B

Comment: It is a Beatifully lemma :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is true. On one hand, since $0 \leq f_n \leq f$ for any $n$, one has 
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \int f_n dm \leq \int f dm.$$
On the other hand, by Fatou's lemma, we have 
$$\int f dm \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int f_n dm.$$
Combining these two inequalities, we conclude 
$$\int f dm = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int f_n dm.$$
Note that here we allow both sides of the identity equal infinity.